# Как получить список нужных фалов из папки

Tags: python-3.x

Здравствующие.

Проблема такая. Мне надо получить список фалов из папки в качестве массива. Однако не всех, а только с расширением CSV. Я пытался использовать glob:

```
directory = 'C:/capstone_user_identification/3users/*.csv' 
All_files = glob.glob(directory)
```

Но получал вот такое:

```
['C:/capstone_user_identification/3users\\test1.csv',
 'C:/capstone_user_identification/3users\\user0001.csv',
 'C:/capstone_user_identification/3users\\user0002.csv',
 'C:/capstone_user_identification/3users\\user0003.csv']
```

Два обратных слеша( Как избавится от них? ХЗ

Потому я попробовал другой способ:

```
directory = 'C:/capstone_user_identification/3users/' 
All_files = os.listdir(directory)
```

И при этом получаю вот такой список:

```
['.DS_Store', 'test1.csv', 'user0001.csv', 'user0002.csv', 'user0003.csv']
```

Все круто... Но мне в этом списке нужны только CSV-фалы( Подскажите, как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно поступить так:

```
In [21]: import os

In [22]: dir_path = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Example'

In [23]: list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.csv'), os.listdir(dir_path)))
Out[23]: ['1.csv', '2.csv', '3.csv']
```